# Change Map background color on Zoom -Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, zooming, background-color

I want to change the background color on zoom.my current background color of the map is blue which I have assigned in the CSS file. on my map I have some markers .when I click on marker it zooms to a specific location on raster tiles. when my map zooms to raster tiles I want to change the map background color to white. How can I change map background color after a certain zoom level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen on the `zoom` event and then add the css class for the zoom.

```
L.DomUtil.addClass(map.getContainer(),'blue-bg');

map.on('zoom',(e)=>{
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  
  if(zoom > 13){
    L.DomUtil.addClass(map.getContainer(),'white-bg');
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(map.getContainer(),'blue-bg');
  }else{
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(map.getContainer(),'white-bg');
    L.DomUtil.addClass(map.getContainer(),'blue-bg');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/4ob7vtnz/

Comment: Falke Design  Thank you so much. This solved my problem. You are a Saviour.